# How to Add SSL and HTTPS in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, ssl

I am trying to add SSL certificate to our website which is build in wordpress CMS.
We already purchased and installed our SSl certificate from our GoDaddy hosting.

After installing this what will be the changes that we need to do in our wordpress CMS.

Could you please explain those steps that will be helpful for us to go ahead with SSL certificate with Padlock and https.

Thanks,
Gopal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to do some changes in `wp_config.php`
make sure `FORCE_SSL_ADMIN` is defined to `true`

```
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);
```

> Points that could help

- Make sure there is no source using `http://`
- you can use .htaccess for force redirecting users to `https://example.com`
- check your console for any errors (regarding mixed content) that's probably because of one or more files loaded without `https://`

> put this to your .htaccess file (if it's not there)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: We did all above changes, Our website url is now https instead http, but we still not getting Green padlock sign before https in chrome and in firefox browser it will showing some exclamation in yellow in padlock. could you please suggest me.

Comment: @Gopal this could be because of mixed content press `F12` or `right click on page > Inspect Element` then click on `console tab` there you will find some message regarding mixed content make sure these links are using https as well

Comment: Yes, it will showing this error:   Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.sanjaypuri.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js?ver=1.0'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Comment: What it is means?

Comment: I am waiting for your valuable reply.

Comment: just use this link `https://assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js?ver=1.0%27` in replace of `http://assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js?ver=1.0%27` where ever it is used

Comment: Actually i have just removed my unwanted plugins regarding pinterest, but still not getting Green padlock in chrome only and when we inspect it it will showing exclamation in yellow:    Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.sanjaypuri.com/' was loaded over a secure connection, but contains a form which targets an insecure endpoint 'http://feedburner.google.com/fb/a/mailverify'. This endpoint should be made available over a secure connection.

Comment: could you please suggest me @Abdul

Comment: check your wordpress configuration and enable SSL also your `favicon.ico` is loaded without `https://` the reason it's still not showing the padlock

Comment: I already added "define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);" in wp-config file, Is anything else we need to add in config file for enabling SSL?

Comment: the site which you mentioned has issue with favicon only, change the link to https:// check this image for reference http://prntscr.com/efkxyz

Comment: Thanks for your valuable support, i also did above changes u can also check, still not getting any padlock....

Answer (score 1):

use this website: https://www.whynopadlock.com/ and enter your website URL. It will run a test and tell you the reason/s why you have no padlock and should also tell you how to fix them.